# how can i show notice on top in my application

Tags: android, notifications

I want to add custom notification in my app so how can i do this in my application : 
[Please Click for Screenshot.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cocoacontrols_production/uploads/control_image/image/641/original.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give the following a try, thit works like a charm: https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Answer (score 1):

You should use custom `Toast`.

An example;

[Custom Toast](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Toast_Alert_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=87&aaid=110/)

Comment: this is usefull tutorial but https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton is perfect :). yani tam olarak aradığım şey :)

Comment: İyiymiş hakkaten bu :D

Comment: şimdi buna bi progress bar ekleyip işlem bitene kadar yukarıda görüntülemek lazım.. facebook uygulaması hesabı ;)

Comment: Kolay gelsin hacı Store'a falan yüklersen link at bakarız bi :D